# Unused parameter warning in templated function with if constexpr

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, c++14, compiler-warnings

In this code

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
void func(const T& a)
{
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,int>)
    {
        static_cast<void>(a);
    }
    else if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T,double>)
    {
        // oops forgot to use it here   
    }
    else
    {
        
    }
}

int main() {
    func(4);
    func("this");
}
```

why doesn't the compiler warn about unused variable in the `else-s()`? (with `-Wall`)

My understanding is that logically the instantiations of the method are completely different. If the argument is not being used in one of the instantiations of the template, isn't it an unused variable?
Or does the language/compiler not interpret it like that.

Comment: Your comment is for `double`, but `main()` instantiates for `char*`. Is this really a [mre], or can it be shorter and demonstrate the problem better, like https://godbolt.org/z/vPWd74naK?

Comment: Don't forget constexpr if is a compile time construct. Only in the case for `int` code will be generated using `a`, for all other types no code is generated for the int part and `a` is not used.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The unused `a` is exactly what the question is about, IMHO.

Comment: Minor point - Neither GCC nor Clang include this warning with `-Wall`. On Clang you will get it with `-Wextra` at least. I would suggest editing the question to mention just the flag you're asking about, which is `-Wunused-parameter`.

Comment: @cigien if i remove `static_cast<void>` it does warn

Comment: Strange, with just `-Wall` I don't get a warning at all https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/875EYa91T

Comment: I really dislike that templates discard so many warnings, not only this one. I'd like to know the reason for that in general. It's like compilers are unable to do that

Comment: @ThomasWeller I now see that I misread the question... unexpected behavior indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can say that the parameter `a` is not fully unused, it's *conditionally* unused.

The C++ standard requires to generate diagnostic messages for ill-formed programs. Your program is not ill-formed. The C++ standard does not require compilers to generate other warnings at all. So it's up to the compiler vendor to decide how to implement that.

While I personally would like to be warned about conditionally unused variables (your example is a good demo why), no compiler vendor has implemented that. Why? They test new version of compilers on large code bases to see whether new C++ features will cause breaking changes. Likely, during those tests, a lot of warnings were generated for code like yours, but the code was considered totally fine by C++ experts. So the warnings were adapted to not occur in such situations. That's to ensure that code with 0 warnings is possible.

Comment: In addition for open-source compilers, if someone feels that a condition is worth having a warning emitted for that situation, implement that warning check for that compiler and submit it.  A warning that is implemented has a much greater chance of being incorporated into the compiler rather than a warning feature request.

Comment: @Eljay: Yes. I could imagine a `-Wconditionally-unused-parameter`, but it looks like that was not requested enough and possibly it would not be included in `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Answer (score 2):

For the same reason you cannot have a syntax error in a discarded branch.

I am assuming you use GCC with `-Wextra`, otherwise I don't get the unused parameter warning.

Consider the following code instead:

```
void func(int arg) {
    if constexpr(false) {
        // discarded branch, so arg should be unused?
        static_cast<void>(arg);
    }
}

int main() {
    func(4);
}
```

If you comment out the `static_cast`, you get the warning `unused parameter 'a'`.

If, instead of the `static_cast`, you do something that should not compile, then it does not compile:

```
void func(int arg) {
    if constexpr(false) {
        int *p = arg; // invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*'
    }
}
```

The compiler looks at the whole function, even if it does not *instantiate* all the branches. That means no error like above¹. That also means that the unused parameter warnings are only thrown if the parameter is not used *anywhere* in the whole function.

¹In the case of a template function, where the validity of an expression can depend on the type of a variable, all expressions in the function must compile given the appropriate types (which can depend on the conditions in `if constexpr` statements). There is also a special case for odr-uses of an undefined entity in a discarded statement.

> A discarded statement is fully checked. `if constexpr` is not a substitute for the #if preprocessing directive.
> ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if))

Comment: Doesn't this `if constexpr(false)` make program ill formed?

Comment: No, the branch just isn't instantiated.

Comment: `// discarded branch, so arg should be unused?`  - yes, please! That's what I expect. Why not?

Comment: "The whole code must compile" - I don't think so: https://godbolt.org/z/5van8vjjf Only the instantiated branches must compile.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I would not expect a warning. I can very well imagine a situation where it only makes sense to use a parameter when some condition is fulfilled, either in a `if constexpr` or just an `if`.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Ok, that statement was wrong, but "only the instantiated branches must compile" is also just plain wrong. See my example, where `if constexpr(false)` certainly does not lead to an instantiation of that branch. I edited to add some nuance.

Comment: I'm not sure what to say about requirements of branches that are not instantiated. They need to be lexically correct and maybe syntactically correct.

Comment: @ThomasWeller In a normal function, they just need to compile like any other parts. In a template, you need to take into account the types that can or cannot end up in an expression. Kind of like template specializations.

Answer (score 0):

the question is
"why doesn't the compiler warn about unused variable in the else-s()? (with -Wall)"

as others have pointed out, the variable IS used within the function.  It is conditionally unused, and you can get that warned about if you set clang to do so, as is pointed out by cigien:

Minor point - Neither GCC nor Clang include this warning with -Wall. On Clang you will get it with -Wextra at least. I would suggest editing the question to mention just the flag you're asking about, which is -Wunused-parameter. –
cigien
yesterday

@ThomasWeller is right and the warning for the conditionally unused parameters is available if you ask clang for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).